# How to use nested JSON in schema

Tags: joi

Trying to setup a nested schema as follows. I want be able to reject the schema if bb.c is present when aa.a is present.

I've tried without as well as xor

```
{
  Joi.object().keys({
    aa: Joi.object().keys({
      a: Joi.string(),
      b: Joi.string()
    }).unknown(true).with("a", "b"),
    bb: Joi.object().keys({
      c: Joi.string()
    }).unknown(true)
  }).xor( "aa.a" , ["bb.c"])
}
```

With the below object xor fails with ValidationError: "value" must contain at least one of [aa.a, bb.c] yet aa.a exists in the supplied values

```
{ 
  "aa": {
       "a": "fg",
       "b": "fg"
 },
  "bb": {
        "c": "l"
   }
}
```

If I try

```
.without( "aa.a" , ["bb.c"])
```

then the schema passes although in my mind it should not pass as without should fail when bb.c is present along with aa.a

Is it because the two things are nested in other objects perhaps?

Can we not specify deeply linked stuff like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use [`Joi.when()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v7.2.2/API.md#anywhenref-options) and create a schema like this:

```
Joi.object({
    aa: Joi.object().keys({
        a: Joi.string(),
        b: Joi.string()
    }).unknown(true).with('a', 'b'),
    bb: Joi.object().keys({
        c: Joi.string()
    }).unknown(true)
        .when('aa.a', {
            is: Joi.exist(),
            then: Joi.object({ c: Joi.forbidden() })    
        })
});
```

Basically what this does is that if **aa.a** is present then the **bb.c** is not allowed and the schema will fail it's validation. With this schema your example will fail as you expect.